# handling multiple buttons with same name and value in one form

Tags: javascript, forms, button

I have multiple submit buttons on a site. They used to move elements up and down and I want to be them in one whole form in case of the user changes meanwhile some other values so everything is saved. The Problem now is I need the element ID of the button which was clicked.

So here is the code in the loop :

```
div class="form-order"><?php echo $elements[$z]['element_order']; ?> </div>
<input type="submit" name="edit_form_operation" value="&#9650;" class="button-primary" 
<?php if($elements[$z]['element_order'] == 1) echo 'disabled="disabled"'; ?> /><br />

<input type="submit" name="edit_form_operation" value="&#9660;" class="button-primary" 
<?php 
$highest_element = $fdb->get_element_highest_order($form[$i]['form_id']);
if($elements[$z]['element_order'] == $highest_element) echo 'disabled="disabled"'; ?> />
```

And onclick of that specific button in the for loop he should write this code first so I know which element has to be moved

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="change_element_id" value="'.$elements[$z]['element_id'].'" >';
```

I'm also open for another solution of this problem.

Comment: If you need the ID of  the button which was clicked, you can use `mybutton.onclick=function(){this.id;}`. But I don't understand very well what you are trying to do...

Comment: I think you're just asking about how to support multiple submit buttons, and know which one was clicked on. See http://www.techrepublic.com/article/handling-multiple-submits-in-a-single-form-with-php/5242116

Comment: Yes but I want to keep the value of the buttons to be the same so that they have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it like that now

Here you process the input:

```
// Select Operation
    if(isset($_POST['edit_form_operation_up'])) {
        echo "move up id ";
        $operation = array_keys($_POST['edit_form_operation_up']);
        echo $operation['0'];
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['edit_form_operation_down'])) {
         echo "move down id ";
         $operation = array_keys($_POST['edit_form_operation_down']);
         echo $operation['0'];
    }
```

And this is in the for loop for infinite Elements the input with same value and name.

```
<?php $elements = $fdb->get_elements($form[$i]['form_id']); 
for($z = 0; $z < sizeof($elements); $z++) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><div class="form-order"><?php echo $elements[$z]['element_order']; ?> </div>
        <input type="submit" name="edit_form_operation_up[<?php echo $elements[$z]['element_id']; ?>]" value="&#9650;" class="button-primary" 
        <?php if($elements[$z]['element_order'] == 1) echo 'disabled="disabled"'; ?> /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="edit_form_operation_down[<?php echo $elements[$z]['element_id']; ?>]" value="&#9660;" class="button-primary" 
        <?php 
        $highest_element = $fdb->get_element_highest_order($form[$i]['form_id']);
        if($elements[$z]['element_order'] == $highest_element) echo 'disabled="disabled"'; ?> />
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $elements[$z]['element_id']; ?> </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

In case of somebody finds this topic and want to find a good solution.

Greetings